# Can't delete kafka topic via zkCli

Tags: apache-kafka

I tried to create kafka topic like:

```
kafka-topics --zookeeper HOST --create --topic TOPIC --partitions 2 --replication-factor 1
```

got error:

`ERROR admin.TopicCommand$: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicExistsException: Topic 'TOPIC' already` exists.

deleting topic didn't help so:

in zoo keeper cli :

```
get /brokers/topics
```

output: list of all topics including TOPIC

```
rmr /brokers/topics/TOPIC
```

no output

```
 get /brokers/topics
```

output: list of all topics that still includes TOPIC

if I try to remove topic that doesn't exist I am getting error:

```
Node does not exist:  /brokers/topics/TOPIC
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for posting the question to soon but maybe it will help others.
There was some process running on another machine querying this topic...

Once I stopped it, topic was deleted.

Comment: Don't be sorry. You helped me. Thank you.